# Excel generation from MYSQL table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pear

My table like this as follows

```
StudentId | Subjects | Marks
----------------------------
   S001   | sub1     |  99
   S002   | sub2     |  80
   S003   | sub3     |  89
   S004   | sub1     |  75
     .
     .
     .
   s100   | sub3     |  60
```

I need to generate an output in excel. So far, I knew how to generate an excel using php pear. Now the question is how to get and pass these values to the worksheet.

My codes,

```
while($records=mysql_fetch.....)
{
$sid[$records['StudentId']]=$records['StudentId'];
$sub[$records['Subjects']]=$records['Subjects'];
$mark[$records['Marks']]=$records['Marks'];
}
$row=2;
$col=0;
$worksheet->write($row,$col,?,$format);
...
...
```

I don't know what values to pass in ? place.
Note: There is no manipulation and all. Simply get the values from table by query fetched in $records. Now need to print the output as like that in table. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Apart from my codes, Is there any other way to get this?thanks advance

Comment: With php pear excel, are you referring to the [`Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer`](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer/redirected) package?

Comment: @Bjoern..Ofcourse, I am using Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer only.

Answer (score 0):

you can add worksheet using `addWorksheet()`

```
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('worksheet name');
if (PEAR::isError($worksheet)) {
    die($worksheet->getMessage());
} 
//$workbook->close();
```

**UPDATE**

you add values like this

```
//for example you have an array like this

$rowCount=0;
$data = array(
  array('', 'Math', 'Literature', 'Science'),
  array('John', 24, 54, 38),
  array('Mark', 67, 22, 57),
  array('Tim', 69, 32, 58),
  array('Sarah', 81, 78, 68),
  array('Susan', 16, 44, 38),
);

foreach ($data as $row) {
  foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    $sheet->write($rowCount, $key, $value);    
  }  
  $rowCount++;
}
```

Comment: @feroz...adding worksheet and generating into excel and all i knew..the problem is how to fetch values from table and pass into $worksheet($row,$col,???????)..Thanks advance..

Comment: It's possible to update like this. But i have more than 100 rows. In that case it's not possible. I am not sure about this. I will check with this...very Thanks @feroz....

Comment: you convert your values as an array then you can simply add the values

Answer (score 0):

This is not your method but you can  generate an output in excel.using this method

```
 <?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "YOUR_MYSQL_USERNAME", "YOUR_MY_SQL_PASSWORD") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("DATABASE_NAME") or die(mysql_error());

    $count = 0;

    $sqlquery = "select * from TABLE_NAME" ;
    $result = mysql_query($sqlquery) or die(mysql_error());  
    $count = mysql_num_fields($result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $header .= mysql_field_name($result, $i)."\t";
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))  {
      $line = '';
      foreach($row as $value)       {
        if(!isset($value) || $value == "")  {
          $value = "\t";
        }   else  {
    # important to escape any quotes to preserve them in the data.
          $value = str_replace('"', '""', $value);
    # needed to encapsulate data in quotes because some data might be multi line.
    # the good news is that numbers remain numbers in Excel even though quoted.
          $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
      }
      $data .= trim($line)."\n";
    }
    # this line is needed because returns embedded in the data have "\r"
    # and this looks like a "box character" in Excel
      $data = str_replace("\r", "", $data);


    # Nice to let someone know that the search came up empty.
    # Otherwise only the column name headers will be output to Excel.
    if ($data == "") {
      $data = "\nno matching records found\n";
    }

    $count = mysql_num_fields($result);



    # This line will stream the file to the user rather than spray it across the screen
     header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    //header("Content-type: text/plain");

    # replace excelfile.xls with whatever you want the filename to default to
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=excelfile.xls");

    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    //echo $header."\n".$data;
    echo $header."\n".$data."\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: It seems useful at the same time it looks complex. I will use these methods in future use...Thanks srinath..

Answer (score 0):

```
$row=2;

while($records=mysql_fetch.....)
{
   $col = 0;
   $sid[$records['StudentId']]=$records['StudentId'];
   $sub[$records['Subjects']]=$records['Subjects'];
   $mark[$records['Marks']]=$records['Marks'];
   $worksheet->write($row,$col++,$records['StudentId'],$format);
   $worksheet->write($row,$col++,$records['Subjects'],$format);
   $worksheet->write($row,$col++,$records['Marks'],$format);
   $row++;
}
```

Comment: @pinu...it's working but it generates last line only(single line).I couldn't get all rows..Thanks in advance..

Comment: I think you are closing the worksheet inside the while loop.
Once the while loop is complete then after the closing bracket close the workbook, not within the while loop.
Within While loop all the rows are created so I think you are closing the workbook inside the loop hence it is showing one record only i.e last record.